"Cannot set property status of [object XMLHttpRequest] which has only a getter" after upgrading Angular 12 to 13
Note: I'm resubmitting a previous question (which I'm deleting) as I've learned more.
I've inherited an application and am working on migrating it to a supported version. It started from Angular 5. I've been going one step at a time, fixing issues and making sure the application still runs, and have been successful from Angular 5 - 12. Now I've hit an issue when going from Angular 12.0.5 to 13.4.0 that I don't know how to resolve. I build the application doing 'ng build', then run it. I'm prompted to enter the user name and password, which appears to be authenticating, but then the "Cannot set property status of [object XMLHttpRequest] which has only a getter" error occurs.
I haven't made any changes to the program code.  I used the upgrade guide https://angular.dev/update-guide?v=12.0-13.0&l=3  for Angular.  I've read through the release notes for typescript 4.4 and I'm not seeing anything that would cause my issue.  I suspect I have some setting that was added for tsconfig.json or angular.json wrong or missing that is causing the build to happen differently, but I have no idea how to start troubleshooting that.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
console output:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property status of [object XMLHttpRequest] which has only a getter          api.model.ts:42 
    at loadXhr (index.js:164:9)
    at XMLHttpRequest.readystatechange [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYreadystatechange] (index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (zone.js:766:39)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:34)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1661:18)
    at globalCallback (zone.js:1692:29)

api.model.ts
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as Model from 'ampersand-model';
import {globals} from "../globals";
import {Query} from "../collections/query.class";


export const ApiModel = Model.extend({
    ajaxConfig: function () {
        return {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': globals.accessToken.id
            }
        };
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.queryFilter = new Query({
            include: {},
            where: {},
            fields: {},
        });
    },

    fetch: function (options) {
        options = _.defaultTo(options, {});
        let success = _.defaultTo(options.success, _.noop);
        let error = _.defaultTo(options.error, _.noop);
        let newOptions = _.defaults({
            success: (model, response, options) => {
                success(model, response, options);
            },
            error: (model, response, options) => {
                if (response.body) {
                    const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
                    if (body.status === 401 || body.error && body.error.statusCode === 401) {
                        window.location.href = '/pages/login';
                    }
                }
                error(model, response, options);
            }
        }, options);

        return Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, newOptions);
    },

    fetchPromise: function (options) {
        options = _.defaultTo(options, {});
        let success = _.defaultTo(options.success, _.noop);
        let error = _.defaultTo(options.error, _.noop);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let newOptions = _.defaults({
                success: (model, response, options) => {
                    resolve(true);
                    success(model, response, options);
                },
                error: (model, response, options) => {
                    resolve(false);
                    error(model, response, options);
                }
            }, options);

            // If GET params are being overridden then don't overwrite them
            if (!options.data) {
                newOptions.data = {filter: JSON.stringify(this.queryFilter.formatQueryFilter())};
            }
            this.fetch(newOptions);
        });
    }
});

snippet from node_modules/xhr/index.js where line 164 is
(xhr.status = xhr.statusCode = status)
// will load the data and add some response properties to the source xhr
// and then respond with that
function loadXhr() {
    var status = getStatusCode()
    var error = errorFromStatusCode(status)

    xhr.status = xhr.statusCode = status
    xhr.body = getBody()
    xhr.headers = parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())

    callback(error, xhr, xhr.body)
}

ng version:
Angular CLI: 13.3.11
Node: 16.20.2
Package Manager: npm 8.19.4
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.4.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router, upgrade

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.11
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.11
@angular/cli                    13.3.11
@schematics/angular             13.3.11
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.4.4


package.json for Angular 13 version:
{
  "name": "coreui-angular",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.6",
  "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
  "author": "",
  "url": "http://coreui.io",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/animations": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "13.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "13.4.0",
    "ampersand": "^3.0.6",
    "ampersand-rest-collection": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-ladda": "^3.2.2",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.23.3",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^13.1.0",
    "q": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ladda": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.33.0",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}


tsconfig.json:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2020"
  }
}


tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}


angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "cli": {
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "coreui-angular": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/CHANGELOG.md"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "ampersand-model",
              "ampersand-rest-collection",
              "rxjs/add/operator/delay",
              "rxjs/add/operator/do",
              "rxjs/add/observable/of",
              "xlsx"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "aot": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "coreui-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "coreui-angular:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "coreui-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/CHANGELOG.md"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "coreui-angular-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "coreui-angular:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "coreui-angular",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}


If you could share the block of code from where the error is being thrown, that would be much more helpful in understanding what the actual issue is. The LOC is pointed out the in the error message.

Added the code for api.model.ts.  Line 42 is "return Model.prototype.fetch.call(this, newOptions);".

Added code snippet for node_modules/xhr/index.js.  Line 164 is "node_modules/xhr/index.js".  The xhr package is a dependency for other packages so I don't understand why it works for Angular 12 but not Angular 13.  Could it have something to do with the View Engine going away in Angular 13?
